# Unity keep the player centered on the screen

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I started with a little topdown game and want to calculate the camera transform when starting the game.

The camera is not set to 90 degrees, it should have like 70. When rotating it, I need the calculate the difference on Z to keep the player in the middle of the screen.

```
public Transform player; // player object
float offsetY = 30; // distance on y
float rotationAngleX = 70; // rotation when looking down

private void Start()
{
    player = Globals.GetPlayerObject().transform; // reference
    transform.Rotate(rotationAngleX, transform.rotation.y, transform.rotation.z); // rotate the camera down
    transform.position = new Vector3(player.position.x, player.position.y + offsetY, player.position.z); // move it to the player
}
```

[image: img]

So what do I need to calculate here, to have the player in the middle? It should always work, so if I change the height on y or rotate the camera by 80 oder 60 degrees, the calculation should work too.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you need to do a little trigonometry here.
If the camera is at 70deg, instead of 90deg, this really means you've got an angle of (90deg-70deg) between the vertical axis and the projected center of the camera.
Since we know that [tan(angle) = opposite/adjacent](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Tangent.html), we can massage this formula around to find the "opposite" distance needed to offset the camera in the Z.

This leaves us with something like: `offsetZ = offsetY*Mathf.Tan(Mathf.Deg2Rad(90f-70f));`
or in your universal case: `offsetZ = offsetY*Mathf.Tan(Mathf.Deg2Rad*(90f-rotationAngleX));`

Therefore if you shift the camera back by the offset amount, the player will be centered.
Beautiful MS Paint picture below should explain.

```
transform.position = new Vector3(player.position.x, player.position.y + offsetY, player.position.z - offsetZ);
```

[image: Trigonometry Visualized]

Comment: Hey, this looks nice.

When writing `float offsetZ = offsetY * Mathf.Tan(Mathf.Deg2Rad(90f - rotationAngleX));` the compiler says, `Mathf.Deg2Rad` can't be used like a method.

It's a value. So I tried to write

`float offsetZ = offsetY * Mathf.Tan(Mathf.Deg2Rad * (90f - rotationAngleX));`

but this did not work, the player stays on the bottom of the screen.

Comment: whoops, fixed. what value do you get for offsetZ at your rotation of 70degrees and y at 30 if you do `Debug.Log(offsetZ);`? it should agree with the math (~10.9f). Did you apply the offset to the camera z position?

Comment: You could use a raycast at start.

Comment: @ryemoss sorry, I made a bug in my late update function. I wrote `transform.position = new Vector3(player.position.x, transform.position.y, player.position.z);`